# How to switch to application, or create new instance if there isn't one?

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to have keyboard shortcuts for opening firefox, nautilus, etc. The problem is that this will always open a new window, instead of using the existing one when there is one. So what can I do about that? Seems like this is not handled by each program so it's not in 'firefox -h'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this really open a new instance or just a new window in the instance? IIRC you can set Firefox to open everything in a new tab instead.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for Firefox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/firefox) says there is a command line option called `-remote <command>` that looks like it does what you want.  The man page in turn points to http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/remote.html for more information about available commands.